# Node.js Writable Stream

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I am new to Node.js world, but catching up well. I mainly read through official docs, because I think those are the most complete thing to read.

Recently I was reading about Streams in Node.js, and wrote a very tiny implementation of ***Writable*** just to test the waters and concepts.

Extending ***Writable*** and calling **write()** on my ***custom Writable*** worked fine. But when I tried to use a simplified approach of merely creating an object of ***Writable*** passing the same tiny implementation, then it worked for the first **write()** but not for subsequent ones. It has left me in a surprise.

**This works**

```
class MyWritable extends Writable {
        constructor(options) {
            super(options)
    }

    write(chunk, encoding, cb) {
        console.log(`MySimpleStream wrote: ${chunk}`)
    }
}
const mw = new MyWritable({decodeStrings: false})
mw.write('1')
mw.write('2')
```

**This doesn't work for second write() call** (see console output)

```
 const myWritableSimpleObj = new Writable({
     write(chunk, encoding, cb) {
         console.log(`MySimpleStream wrote: ${chunk}`)
     },
     decodeStrings: false
 })

 myWritableSimpleObj.write('My simple writable stream...')
 myWritableSimpleObj.write('Some more data.')
```

Console output:

```
nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/implementWritable.js`
MySimpleStream wrote: 1
MySimpleStream wrote: 2
MySimpleStream wrote: My simple writable stream...
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: You're not calling the callback `cb` after the `console.log` to acknowledge the write.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer  @JoachimIsaksson, but nowhere in the official Node docs this has been pointed out.

Comment: The mention is there about calling the callback once the chunk is written to the target. Sorry for confusion.